# how to create multiple pages in Xcode iphone apps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa-design-patterns

i am starting my experience with iphone sdk. and i have a question, which is i am trying to create two pages to the app but i don't know how to link them or design them. like when i start the Xcode i find one page named View to design in it, i want to make that page a welcoming page then the user choose one of the three choices he see in that page. Once he clicked on one of them the program take him to the next page or the page he chose.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach on iPhone is a drill-down. Place a UINavigationController in your NIB, make the root-level view your welcome page. Then navigate to dependent views by invoking pushViewController on that navigation controller.

This is a very high-level description; you'd have to fill a lot of blanks. If you create a new project and specify a "navigation-based application", you'll get quite a bit of boilerplate code for this approach.

Comment: How would you do the same thing in a Mac app?

Comment: This UI makes no sense for a Mac-sized screen. The whole reason for showing no more than one level of navigation at a time is the screen size. On a computer, you can do a tree/details kind of UI - think XCode.

Answer (score 1):

You really need a good book, I recommend [Beginning iPhone 3 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592) by Apress.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using `UIViewController`'s

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method. You can display your initial view, and when the user presses one of the buttons, display the intended view over top. If you build a new project, and choose "Utility Application" you will get some sample code for how this works.